# How can I have a clickable image and link (anchor) in a list item

Tags: html, css, styles

As mentioned in the title, i want to get an icon and an a tag inside a li.

I want a small icon to the left of the text in a navigation bar but also have the entire bar clickable.

I tried to google it but without and results.

My current situation looks like this:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="../resources/images/test.png" /><a href="#text">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#test">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#test">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#test">Test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#test">Test4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li a {
    margin-right: 50px;
    background: #B0AA9A;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #454138;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    float: left
}
```

Comment: Why did you expect that something outside your anchor would act as though it was inside it?

Comment: @isherwood I dont usually work with CSS/HTML so i need to get back in. Im not too much into all the rules and stuff.

Comment: Sure. Just remember that something not inside something isn't inside that something. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this, 
Put the Img inside the A tag and then both will be clickable to whatever href you give.

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    Login
    <img src="../resources/images/test.png" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#test">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#test">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#test">Test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#test">Test4</a></li>
</ul>
```